# How to deploy and run only GO app binary on GCP?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I would like to deploy a `GO` app without revealing app's source code. Say I have multiple customers that I'm selling my application to. The goal is to setup their `GCP` accounts, deploy binary, run the app and hand all the credentials to `GCP` account so they can `stop/pause/pay` etc. themselves. And I'm out.

What I've tried is deploying my app to `Google App Engine` and everything works nicely, but what I'd like to do is to `"hide/restrict"` the source code to be accessible. In short I'd like to deploy binaries only and not my source code.

What are my options? Thank you!

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This question is close to the line, but developers will find it useful and we have a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloud Run. Build your container with your GO binary in your project. Then grant the customers projects to access to your Container registry (so not your code, only your container with the binary already compiled) and deploy the container on Cloud Run.

Grant the permission as before with app Engine (Very similar) and that's it!